# What is replacement for Android's Floating Button in iOS?

Tags: android, ios, material-design, human-interface-guideline

I wanted to build functionality in Android using a floating button, as all the tabs are fixed.

What is the solution for replacing Floating Button in iOS?

Comment: The Floating Action Button (FAB) is part of the google's material design description. If you are planning to use the material design for an iOS app there is nothing stopping you. I mean not on a moral UX grounds, but there are plenty of apps already doing it and going good :)

Comment: Thank You Himanshu....I started doing same...but just wanted a confirmation weather iOS Users are they aware of floating button

Comment: No problems with that at all. 
FABs are instant attention grabbers anyways - the design philosophy behind was derived from keeping a crystal clear call to action which screams "Click Me" so don't worry about that :)

Answer (score 4):

As [Himanshu Vaishnav mentioned](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/99753/what-is-replacement-for-androids-floating-button-in-ios#comment160746_99753), there's no prohibition on using a [Floating Action Button (FAB)](https://material.google.com/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html) on iOS, but it's decidedly a part of Google's [Material Design system](https://material.google.com). And while Material Design is a nice system, it does come into direct conflict with Apple's [iOS 10 Human Interface Guidelines (HIG)](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/) at varying points—often ending up with apps that feel a bit like an Android app running on an iOS device (and I say this as a designer on an iOS app that employs Material Design interactions and components).

Sticking to the letter of the HIG, there's no direct translation into iOS style for a single, promoted action. However, you might consider placing the primary action(s) in the upper-right corner of the [Navigation Bar](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/navigation-bars/) (this is particularly useful if you have a [Tab Bar](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/tab-bars/) at the bottom, since you're not supposed to have actions mixed in with navigation in that component)...

> Sometimes, the right side of a navigation bar contains a control, such as an Edit or a Done button, for managing content within the active view.

[image: iOS Navigation Bar]

...or, you can use a [Toolbar](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/toolbars/) to present actions as icon buttons or text buttons in the "thumb zone" at the bottom of the screen.

> A toolbar appears at the bottom of an app screen and contains buttons for performing actions relevant to the current view or content within it.

[image: iOS Toolbar]

In general, the "right answer" of how to present your app's actions is going to be very case-specific to your app and your users.

Comment: What if the action that fab is trying to represent is on a card? The Material allows that there be a fab on each card for example to add a row similar to the previous card. Putting the action in the toolbar or the navigation bar does not totally represent the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possible to have a FAB button in Apple iOS. Have a look at the Google Calendar app on [iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/google-calendar-make-the-most-of-every-day/id909319292?mt=8)

[image: Image og Google Calendar App on iTunes Store]